# Least-square method scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr return false exact solution

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I'm trying to find the least squares solution x that minimizes norm(b-A*x) with

```
A=[[-1, 1, 0]
   [0, -1, 1]
   [-1, 0, 1]]
```

and

```
b=[1, 1, -1]
```

So I made the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr

b=np.array([1.,1.,-1.], dtype=float)
A=csc_matrix([[-1., 1.,0.], [0., -1., 1.], [-1., 0., 1.]], dtype=float)
x=lsqr(A,b)[0]
```

And I get

```
The exact solution is  x = 0                              
array([0., 0., 0.])
```

So apparently Ax=b admits an exact solution as the zero vector, but here Ax=[0,0,0] which is clearly not b.
When I try this with other values for b I get some result that seems acceptable, but here I really don't understand the output.
I have the feeling that I am missing some completely obvious stuff.

Comment: Your matrix A is singular (the determinant of A is 0), thus there's no nontrivial solution to the non-homogeneous linear system Ax=b

Comment: @joni Yes I know there is no exact solution to the system Ax=b since my matrix is singular, that's why I try to use the least square method in order to approximate x and minimize the norm norm(Ax-b),

Comment: Its not that there is no exact solution, if you have `det A = 0` then you will have an infinte number of solutions & computers dont like that. See this question on Math Stack -  [Finding a solution when the determinant is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933668/finding-a-solution-when-the-determinant-is-zero)

Comment: @DrBwts According to your link there is an infinite number of solution if we are in the case were " b is in the column space of A but det(A)=0."  In my case b is not in a column of A, so we have no solution.